# .NET MAUI MVVM View Initialization doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

I am trying to write a program using .NET MAUI with MVVM community tookit. I am following the official practice from *Enterprise Application Patterns using .NET MAUI*, the source code of which can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eshop-mobile-client/tree/main).

I have defined the `IViewModelBase` and implemented it with `ViewModelBase` just like the example app does:

```
//IViewModeBase.cs
using Music_Journal.Services.Navigation;

namespace Music_Journal.ViewModels.Base {
    public interface IViewModelBase : IQueryAttributable {
        public INavigationService NavigationService { get; }
        public bool IsBusy { get; }
        public bool IsInitialized { get; }
        Task InitializeAsync();
    }
}



//IViewModeBase.cs
using Music_Journal.Services.Navigation;

namespace Music_Journal.ViewModels.Base {
    public abstract partial class ViewModelBase : ObservableObject, IViewModelBase {

        private long _isBusy;
        public bool IsBusy => Interlocked.Read(ref _isBusy) > 0;

        [ObservableProperty]
        private bool _isInitialized;

        public INavigationService NavigationService { get; }
        public IAsyncRelayCommand InitializeAsyncCommand { get; }


        public ViewModelBase(INavigationService navigationService) {
            NavigationService = navigationService;
            InitializeAsyncCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(
                async () => {
                    await IsBusyFor(InitializeAsync);
                    IsInitialized = true;
                },
                AsyncRelayCommandOptions.FlowExceptionsToTaskScheduler
            );
        }

        public virtual void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> query) { }

        public async Task IsBusyFor(Func<Task> unitOfWork) {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref _isBusy);
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsBusy));

            try {
                await unitOfWork();
            } finally {
                Interlocked.Decrement(ref _isBusy);
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsBusy));
            }
        }

        public virtual Task InitializeAsync() {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

In one ViewModel called `ProjectPageViewModel`, I overwrite the `InitializeAsync` function from the `ViewModelBase` like this:

```
using Music_Journal.Models;
using Music_Journal.Services.Navigation;
using Music_Journal.Services.Projects;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;


namespace Music_Journal.ViewModels {
    public partial class ProjectPageViewModel : ViewModelBase {
        private IProjectStorage _projectStorage;
        public ObservableCollection<Project> Projects { get; } = new();

        public ProjectPageViewModel (
                IProjectStorage projectStorage,
                INavigationService navigationService)
                : base (navigationService) {
            _projectStorage = projectStorage;
        }

        // Initialization
        private RelayCommand _initializeCommand;
        public RelayCommand InitializeCommand => _initializeCommand ??= new RelayCommand(
            async () => {
                await _projectStorage.InitializeAsync();
        });

        // Add Project
        private RelayCommand _addProjectCommand;
        public RelayCommand AddProjectCommand => _addProjectCommand ??= new RelayCommand(
            async () => {
                var p = new Project();
                p.Name = "test project";
                await _projectStorage.AddAsync(p);
        });

        // Read all Projects and put them into this viewmodel
        private RelayCommand _listProjectsCommand;
        public RelayCommand ListProjectsCommand => _listProjectsCommand ?? new RelayCommand(
            async () => {
                var list = await _projectStorage.ListAsync();
                Projects.Clear();
                foreach (var p in list) {
                    Projects.Add(p);
                }
            }
        );

        // NOTE HERE
        public override async Task InitializeAsync() {
            await IsBusyFor(
                async () => {
                    var list = await _projectStorage.ListAsync();
                    Projects.Clear();
                    foreach (var p in list) {
                        Projects.Add(p);
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the `ProjectPageView`:

```
using Music_Journal.ViewModels;

namespace Music_Journal.Views;
public partial class ProjectsPage : ContentPage
{
    public ProjectsPage(ProjectPageViewModel projectPageViewModel) {
        InitializeComponent();
                BindingContext = projectPageViewModel;
    }
}
```

I think since I have overwritten the `InitializeAsync` method, the initialization should be runned once I navigate to the project page. After debugging, however, it seems that when page is initialized, the program will not go through the `InitializeAsync` method from the `ViewModelBase`, nor the overwritten `InitializeAsync` method from the `ProjectPageViewModel`. Why is that?

I also tried to explicitly call the InitializeAsync method on `ProjectPageView.cs`. And this time, everything works fine:

```
//ProjectPageView.cs
using Music_Journal.ViewModels;

namespace Music_Journal.Views;
public partial class ProjectsPage : ContentPage
{
    private ProjectPageViewModel viewModel;
    public ProjectsPage(ProjectPageViewModel projectPageViewModel) {
        InitializeComponent();
        viewModel = projectPageViewModel;
        BindingContext = projectPageViewModel;
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
        => await viewModel.InitializeAsync();
}
```

I am confused. Why the `InitializeAsync` method won't be called automatically when the page is initialized? How can I fix this without explicitly calling it in the code-behind of the xaml file?

Comment: Have you tried subscribing to Loaded event instead of calling from constructor? Async methods in constructor usually cause problems...

Comment: In the sample they are using a ContentPageBase class that calls InitializeAsync in OnAppearing

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).